# Shouldn't a change event on collection also fire a change event on the model?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

When I run `add` on my collection:

```
this.children.add(newData,{merge:true});
```

The change event for the collection fires and tells me the model that has changed. However, that model that has changed does not fire a change event.  I would think that if the model changed it would fire a change event.

In the individual item view I have (`ChildView.js`):

```
initalize: function(){
    this.listenTo(this.model, 'change',this.render);
},
```

And in the View for all the items I have (`ChildrenView.js`):

```
this.listenTo(this.children, 'change', this.changed);
```

So `this.changed` DOES fire.  But the model in question does not fire a `change event`

I am doing an ajax file upload so for lack of a better way right now I am just using an ajax call to upload the file (See the success function where it sets the collection):

```
    getFile:function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var that = this;
        var collChildren = this.children;
        console.log('this',this);
        console.log(this.children);
        var file = e.target.files[0];
        var formData = new FormData($('#upload-child-pic-form')[0]);
        console.log(this,'currentUploadU',this.currentUpload);
        formData.append('child_id',this.currentUpload);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/x/children/upload/',  //Server script to process data
            type: 'POST',
            xhr: function() {  // Custom XMLHttpRequest
            var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                if(myXhr.upload){ // Check if upload property exists
                    myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',function(data){
                        $("#upload-child-pic-progress").val(data.position / data.totalSize * 100);
                    }, false); // For handling the progress of the upload
                }
                return myXhr;
            },
            //Ajax events
            beforeSend: function(data){
                $("#upload-child-pic-progress").removeClass('hide');
            },
            success: function(data){
                $("#upload-child-pic-progress").addClass('hide');
                $("#add-child-profile-pics-modal").modal('hide');
                var newData = $.parseJSON(data);
                collChildren.add(newData,{merge:true});
            },
            error: function(data){
                console.log('error',data);
            },
            // Form data
            data: formData,
            //Options to tell jQuery not to process data or worry about content-type.
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });
    },
```

Here is my Single `Child` View

```
define([
'jquery',
'underscore',
'backbone',
'text!templates/children/child.html'
], function($,_,Backbone,childTemplate){
var ChildView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',

    events: {
        'click .pic-settings'   : 'picSettingsClicked',
    },

    template: _.template(childTemplate),

    initalize: function(){
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'change',this.render);
    },

    picSettingsClicked: function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        Backbone.pubsub.trigger('picSettingClick',this.model.get('id'));
    },

    render: function(){
        console.log('changing',this.model,this.model.get('photo'),this.model.get('first_name'));
        this.$el.addClass('child').html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
}); 
return ChildView;
});
```

Comment: If the initialize is inside your model, does your model have a render function?

Comment: Yes. It does. And a console.log which is not tracing.

Comment: Are you sure you have not swapped the two? Why would you have `this.render` in the model? If you really have that in the model, then having `this.model` in the model makes no sense and you should just be using `this`.

Comment: Sorry. I do not initialize inside my model. the `initialize` is inside the individual item view. The listento change is inside the view for all the individual items. See my edit. Thanks for noticing that.

Comment: if you are adding models, isn't it true that the model that you are listening too isn't changing, but new models are being added? In that case, it would make sense that the model referenced in `ChildView.js` isn't changing

Comment: I am merging them. The model being added has the same id as one in the collection. In the change event of the collection shows that there is a change in the model. That change is just not dispatching to the model.

Comment: I created fiddle using just plain model / collection and it works for case you illustrated: http://jsfiddle.net/M5J8Q/1018/
Events are correctly invoked. Are you sure, that 'newData' has correct id?
Also, problem might be somewhere in rest of code, which we cannot see, could you share also that?

Comment: Thanks @drax. I added more code above.